# What is the most db efficient way to get specific fields of a foreign key in a queryset using Wagtail page models

Tags: django, django-views, wagtail

So I have this model:

```py
class FieldPosition(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey('PlayerDetailPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='field_position_relationship')
    field_position = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Field position'), max_length=3, choices=FIELD_POSITION_CHOICES, null=True)
```

And this Wagtail page model:

```py
class PlayerDetailPage(Page):

    content_panels = [ InlinePanel('field_position_relationship', label=_('Field position'), max_num=3), ]
```

I made a property in the page model:

```py
@property
def position(self):
    position = [
        n.field_position for n in self.field_position_relationship.all()
        ]
        return position
```

So I can access the `field_position` in my template with:

```py
{% for p in  page.position %}
{{ p }}
{% endfor %}
```

But is there any better way to do this? I feel like I am hitting the database too much and I have a lot of queries. I would prefer something like:
`PlayerDetailPage.objects.values('field_position_relationship__field_position')`

But then I get the values of **all PlayerDetailPage entries** , I just want the value of the particular page that is displaying. How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this is what you're after. It is the combination of the two answers you had.

```
@property
def position(self):
    return self.field_position_relationship.values('field_position')
```